# MSSQL/Entity Framework OrderBy if exists?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Wondering if I could get some assistance with this syntax?  I've tried various forms of "Exists" and "IsNull" and I just can't get it.

I have three tables:

```
Item            Package     ItemsInPackages
-----------     -------     ---------------
ItemID          PackageID   ID
Name            Desc        PackageID
Desc                        ItemID
```

Now,  I would like to return a list of all items in existence...

```
SELECT * FROM Items
```

but now I want to sort that, so that I can float all the [Items] that exist in [PackageID]=5 to the top of the result set.

I.e pseudo code...

```
ORDER BY (ROW EXIST [ItemsInPackages].PackageID = 5) Something Something DESC?
```

Using MSSQL 2008 & Entity Framework 7.  Either EF or TSQL syntax would work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting the other rows to still be returned as well? Meaning, all rows that have PackageID = 5 will be returned first, then the remaining rows will be returned after?

Comment: Correct.  Wanting all rows returned, but have all Items part of the package be at the top.

Comment: Care to offer any feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
select *
  from Items as I
  order by case
    when exists ( select 42 from ItemsInPackages as IIP where IIP.ItemID = I.ItemID and IIP.PackageID = 5 ) then 0
    else 1 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Not tested

```
SELECT * FROM Items
WHERE [ItemsInPackages].PackageID = 5
ORDER BY [ItemsInPackages] DESC;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that SQL Server doesn't support ordering by a table, regardless of direction. Referencing a table in a `WHERE` clause without using it in a `SELECT` or `FROM` clause, and with no attempt to correlate it with the `Items` table, won't work terribly well.